# How do I turn off warnings when compiling a kernel?

Tags: c, compilation, clang, compiler-warnings, pragma

I'm trying to compile an android kernel using clang and I'm getting warnings that I don’t care about. For compilation I use the command `make -j3 CC=clang O=output`, so I cannot just add the `-Wno-everything` argument as if I were using the command `clang file.c`. As I understand it, I can disable some warnings by adding `#pragma` to the file that causes the error. But also I have one strange error that does not reference any file:

```
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-vectorizer-no-neon' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

How can I turn off all warnings? Or at least this one.

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: Presumably `-Wno-unknown-warning-option` would turn the warning about unknown options off.  But the other question is "Why is an unknown warning option being passed to the compiler?" — it would be a good idea to resolve that if you can.  In general, you want to know about warnings, especially in a kernel, because they usually indicate bugs in your code.  This one is rather different, though — if your code doesn't use the feature that it is warning you is missing, it isn't critical to you or your module (kernel).

Comment: What exact compiler versions are you using?

Comment: It depends on the Makefile, but often you can pass `CFLAGS` to add additional compiler arguments: `CFLAGS=-Wno-everything`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, it really looks like a solution, but there are a lot of CFLAGS in my makefile). Looks like I'll have to try everything :D

Comment: @Cheatah clang-r428724 (13.0.1)

Comment: @Thomas In general, I tried many parameters, and found the one I needed: ARCH_CPPFLAGS

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the `-Wno-everything` argument to the `ARCH_CPPFLAGS` parameter in the `Makefile`.

Comment: Doing a `make ARCH_CPPFLAGS=-Wno-error -C linux-4.19.107/tools/perf` doesn't seem to work for me, still fails with `cc1: error: function may return address of local variable [-Werror=return-local-addr]`.